# Multithreaded program only runs on a single processor after compiling, how do I troubleshoot?

Tags: unix, bioinformatics

I am trying to run a compiled [program](http://www.genome.umd.edu./quorum.html) that is supposed to be running on multiple processors. But with the same data, sometimes this program runs in parallel and sometimes it won't (with the identical PBS script file!). I am suspecting that something is wrong with some of the compute nodes that won't let it run on parallel (I don't get to choose the compute node I want). How can I troubleshoot if this is a bug in the program or it is problem with the compute node?
As per the sys admin's adivce, I am using `ulimit -s 100000`, but this don't change anything. Also, this program is not an mpi program (runs only on a single node, with multiple processors).
The code that I run is as follows:

```
quorum_error_correct_reads -q 68 \
--contaminant=/data004/software/GIF/packages/masurca/2.3.0rc1/bin/../share/adapter.jf \
-m 1 -s 1 -g 1 -a 3 --thread=32 -w 10 -e 3 \
quorum_mer_db.jf aa.renamed.fastq ab.renamed.fastq ac.renamed.fastq ad.renamed.fastq ae.renamed.fastq af.renamed.fastq ag.renamed.fastq \
--no-discard -o pe.cor --verbose
```

Thanks for any advice you can offer. I will greatly appreciate your help!
PS: I don't have sudo access.

EDIT: I know it is supposed to be using multiple processors because, when I SSH into the node and do `top -c` I can see (above command) sometimes running  like `3200 % CPU` (all the time) and sometimes only `100 % CPU` all the time. This is the only step involved and there are no other sub-process within this program. Also, I am using HPC, where I submit the job to a compute node, each with 32 procs, 512GB RAM.

Comment: How do you know its supposed to be running on multiple processors?  Also, you mention _compute node_, this is not the same as multiple processors. So please add some clarity to your question.

Comment: Multi-threaded does not imply multi-process. A Single process may have multiple threads. The multi-threaded single process may also have CPU affinity. Don't expect a multi-threaded single process to be running on multiple CPU.